# How to determine source of this roof leak?

Tags: leak, roof, waterproofing, roofing, shingles

As Irma pounds our house I was in the attic and noticed we have a roof leak but I can't figure exactly where it is coming from. The obvious place is where that exhaust vent is penetrating, but it is complete dry at that point. Tips on correcting this?

[image][image]

Comment: Have you gone out and inspected the exterior of the roof for anything out-of-the-ordinary?  ... Also, you're ok with there being only 2x4s and pressboard between you and Irma, you might want to send your resume to the Avengers...

Comment: Haha, just getting a lot of rain here. I was up there yesterday. The roof is 2 years old (added by previous owner) and that vent appears to be sealed. Kind of a mystery to me how water is getting through.

Comment: Show us the weather side, please. Where it ends up isn't as important as where it comes from.

Comment: Those do actually look like 2x4's, please tell me that it is not and it is a trick of the eye? Also, just curious here, (it goes to the question fo show us the weather side of the roof) but did he put the vent fan UNDER the run of shingles below it? that would allow the water to pass one run fully, then leak where you are picturing.